# How to avoid Ice Storm Scroll suicide

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a scroll of Ice Storm. Whenever I try to cast it, the storm seems to be centered on me. It inflicts damage on me and my follower, quickly killing us.

From reading the UESP and Wikia pages on Ice Storm, it sounds like it's supposed to be a slow-moving projectile launched at my target. When I cast Fireball it acts as I would expect, launching the spell away from me at my target. But Ice Storm seems to be a self-focused and self-detrimental area of effect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ice Storm *should* [look like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSjD1t99cKU&t=2m13s) when you cast it. That's not what you're getting?

Comment: No... but it looks remarkably like Blizzard. Upon investigation, one of my mods (Better Sorting) mistakenly renamed Blizzard Scroll to Ice Storm Scroll. I was aiming at a target, but Blizzard has such a large AoE that everyplace is within its radius, hence the confusion. If you'll post your question as an answer, I'll accept it in case other people get bit by this bug.

Comment: Since I really had no idea what was wrong and I just accidentally fed you a bit of info you needed to solve the problem, and since it's totally OK to self-answer here, why don't you post the full investigation as an answer?

Comment: Weird. After deactivating and re-activating all my mods, Better Sorting names the scroll properly. I plan to shut down this question since it appears to be an installation-specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case others hit this or a similar problem:

My inventory showed an Ice Storm scroll, but the item was actually a [Blizzard](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blizzard) scroll. Blizzard has a very large area of effect, so casting in a tight dungeon area left me within the AoE, leading to my confusion and self-[Destruction](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_%28Skyrim%29).

I tracked the problem down to the (otherwise excellent) [Better Sorting mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/2730/?). Disabling it showed me the scroll's true identity. During the troubleshooting process I ended up disabling and then re-enabling all my mods. That fixed the inventory naming glitch.

So this might have been a problem with Better Sorting itself, or a conflict between Better Sorting and another mod. Regardless, disabling and re-enabling solved the problem.

Comment: You might want to try the [Sharlikrans Compatibility Patch version of Better Sorting](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/26230/). It has been modified to be updated and cleaned with TES5Edit. Also, use [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/6/?) to sort and optimize your mod load order.